# How to export shapefiles to KML in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to export shapefiles in KML format using openlayers or javascript
Is it possible to do so?
Thanks in advance for reply

Answer (score 0):

- First part is the shapeFiles: You have to import them with the help
  of your QuantumGIS or shapeFileImporter or some other instrument
  meant to work with shapefiles and your database connector or
  mapServer. If you want more information to this topic, you have to
  provide more details. E.g. what spatial DB do you use, what kind of
  mapServer do you use and so on. Importing shapeFiles with the help of
  openLayers may be possible with [this](http://indicatrix.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/shapefiles-in-openlayers/) but i haven't tested it yet
  and it could be very vulnerable and not very easy going, because the
  shapefiles are binary...
- Second part is the KML export: If you have a vectorLayer in OL, you
  can get a feature collection and pass it to the OpenLayers.Format.KML
  to a write function and it produces the KML structured string... I
  havne't tested it, but this should work:

  var myKMLparser = new OpenLayers.Format.KML;

  var myKMLStructuredString = myKMLparser.write(myVectorLayer.features);

[here you can find the documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html) to this parser...