# how to export shapefiles in KML format in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers

I want to export shapefiles in KML format using OpenLayers or ExtJS. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks drnextgis for your quick reply.Is it possible to use ogr2ogr in openlayers or extjs? if possible please give some example or code. And does ogr2ogr needs any plugin to add in program?

Comment: What do you mean by *"export shapefiles in KML format"*? You don't mean "Esri shapefile", do you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export shapefiles to KML in openlayers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091578/how-to-export-shapefiles-to-kml-in-openlayers)

Comment: I want to export shapefiles in kml format programatically using extjs when user click on button.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers is not suit for such task. You can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) for example:

```
ogr2ogr -f KML output.kml input.shp
```

Comment: Thanks drnextgis for your quick reply.Is it possible to use ogr2ogr in openlayers or extjs? if possible please give some example or code. And does ogr2ogr needs any plugin to add in program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)
to import shape files and it will give you a link in wms or wfs or kml to use in your application.You can also style your map.